# I have an existing Django Webapp, how do I make a rest API to integrate the webapp with an android app?

Tags: python, android, django, rest

I have an existing django webapp, I have two model classes in my models.py for different functionalities in my app. **I have used django allauth for all of the login/logout/social sign ins**. **Note: I have not used django rest framework at all so far in creating my app.**
Now, I have to do the same for the android version of my webapp using Java. What exactly do I need to do right now to create the rest APIs and then connect them to the android app? please give some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

[`dj-rest-auth`](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth) Drop-in API endpoints for handling authentication securely in Django Rest Framework. it depends on `django allauth`, easy to integrate and have a good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to create new rest API for the android apps. Authentication will be token based for the rest API. storing tokens and retrieving data will be handled by the android app.
The stable authentication for Django is Simplejwt